# How to split .txt according the column?

Tags: python, text

I have a file.txt and it looks like:

```
02461 03450 02678
02299 02499 04987
04663 01056 03029
04532 01186 01297
.......
```

and I want to split it into three columns with data type string.(without using for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) which will return a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None, sep='\s+', dtype=str)
```

Then you can use `df[0].to_list()` etc. to get each column.

Comment: But the first 0 will be deleted, 02461 will be converted into 2461